Nexus 8 Gear Hub spring not working
After a long trouble shooting with my Nexus 8 Gear Hub and other maintenance on my bike I wanted to put the rear wheel back. I did open the gear hub, but I never disassembled any of the internals. I believe I've assembled everything according to spec. But after inserting the shifter cable back in place I've noticed, that I'm no longer able to shift through gears. I believe there was some kind of spring mechanism that was either pulling up or down, I don't remember, while the cable and shifter where pulling the other direction. However there seems no tension at all. Did I miss or broke some spring? For the life of me, I can't figure out what was causing the previous spring/tension, and what is causing that not to work right now. Any ideas?

Just curious if you resolved this. I'm having exactly the same issue with the lack of spring tension after cleaning and lubricating the hub.

No, unfortunately not. I got quite demotivated and the bike is still disassembled in the basement :(

There's basically not enough information here.

What model? If you did have a return spring failure in the internal assembly, or a failure of one of the parts between it and the cassette joint, your first step is pull the ev document from si.shimano.com, then see what part number(s) contain the broken part, then see of those what's available for purchase if any.
The real first step here is take the wheel back off, take the cassette joint off, and test by grasping hard whether the driver plate is returning normally. The driver plate is the splined thing that the cassette joint engages on to and turns to shift the hub - basically the driver plate is the internal mechanism's interface with the outside world. If it's not returning, something is broken or wrong inside. If it is returning, the cassette joint or cable system was broken or wrong. The cassette joint being put together wrong and just not engaging with the splines correctly sounds pretty likely here, but I don't know.


I'd guess, from my limited experience with the nexus 7, that either the housing end stop or the inner cable end stop isn't in place.
Alternatively the plastic mechanism that turns cable pull into rotary motion of the shift ring on the hub isn't properly engaged. That's fiddly to get right.
On that mechanism there's a little window with two marks that should line up in a specific gear (4th on the nexus 7, which has yellow marks). As you twist the shifter one moves with respect to the other, even if that shift mechanism isn't on the hub. So checking that has some diagnostic value
